# How do I change the window position in Unrealscript?

Tags: udk, scripting

So when I start my game it starts out in the middle of my screen at 1024x768 resolution, but then when I change the resolution via `consolecommand("SETRES ...");` it resets the window position to the top left of my desktop.

Is there a way for me to set the windows position after I make this change?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there isn't; I think `SETRES` is intended to be used in conjunction with the game running in (or toggling almost immediately to) full-screen.

However, it's possible that you could [write a C++ extension DLL](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/869310-Tutorial-Building-a-C-DLL-and-script-class-to-list-graphics-resolutions) to provide yourself a scripting command to move the window (you'd want to use Win32 method to locate the window and call `SetWindowPos` probably).

It's also possible that you can achieve what you want by setting the appropriate values in the [viewport frame](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/UE3%3aGameViewportClient_%28UDK%29#ViewportFrame) of the game client object, if you have access to it.